# How do I install updates from Windows.old folder? for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, reinstall

Ran into some troubles lately, and tried to refresh/restore my Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit PC, but couldn't.
So, I just installed (Custom Installation) the same OS again from the recovery media I created, and all the files there as usual moved to the windows.old folder.

Now, I am having this issue: Windows 10 is ought to release soon, and I had reserved a free upgrade. To get that app, I need to install some GBs of updates all over again which I had already installed before.

So, is there a way to get Windows 10 (the upgrade I had reserved before, in the app, which went missing after the re-install) without downloading those updates?

And is there any way to install those updates from the windows.old folder?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Okay, so downloading the iso and running it will work? No need to reserve it or anything?

Comment: I thought upgrading via the app wouldn't result in a windows.old folder? Would that mean I lose all the softwares I installed all over again?

Comment: My windows is already windows 8.1. But has no updates installed. I want to save broadband, but from your replies I get the impression that you are not very knowledgeable on the subject than me or you didn't understand my question properly. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way to get Windows 10 (the upgrade I had reserved
>   before, in the app, which went missing after the re-install) without
>   downloading those updates?

Even if you were to use the [.ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) to install Windows 10, those updates are still required, because it is unlikely you currently have **Windows 8.1 Update** installed which is a requirement for Windows 10.  Feel free to determine if you do have it installed yourself, if you do have it installed, then you are already set to upgrade to Windows 10

> I thought upgrading via the app wouldn't result in a windows.old
>   folder? Would that mean I lose all the softwares I installed all over
>   again?

It can result in the creation of the Windows.old folder it entirely depends on several factors.

> Okay, so downloading the iso and running it will work? No need to
>   reserve it or anything?

Yes.  You can also just install the updates and then accept the update through Windows Updates itself.  The "Get Windows 10" application isn't required to install Windows 10.  **Windows 8.1 Update** is required to receive future updates on **Windows 8.1** so Microsoft specifically lists that particular update in the requirements to install Windows 10.

> Latest OS:
>
> Make sure you are running the latest version of either Windows 7 SP1
>   or Windows 8.1 Update.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications)